# Cassandra digest mismatch exception running docker container in DCOS

Tags: cassandra, mesos, mesosphere, dcos

Cassandra is giving digest mismatch error. Restarting service on all nodes isn't helping.

```
ERROR 10:55:11 Exception in thread Thread[HintsDispatcher:2,1,main]
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSReadError: java.io.IOException: Digest mismatch exception
at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsReader$HintsIterator.computeNext(HintsReader.java:199) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.14.jar:3.0.14]
at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsReader$HintsIterator.computeNext(HintsReader.java:164) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.14.jar:3.0.14]
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:47) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.14.jar:3.0.14]
at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatcher.sendHints(HintsDispatcher.java:157) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.14.jar:3.0.14]
at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatcher.sendHintsAndAwait(HintsDispatcher.java:139) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.14.jar:3.0.14]
at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatcher.dispatch(HintsDispatcher.java:123) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.14.jar:3.0.14]
at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatcher.dispatch(HintsDispatcher.java:95) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.14.jar:3.0.14]
at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatchExecutor$DispatchHintsTask.deliver(HintsDispatchExecutor.java:268) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.14.jar:3.0.14]
at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatchExecutor$DispatchHintsTask.dispatch(HintsDispatchExecutor.java:251) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.14.jar:3.0.14]
at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatchExecutor$DispatchHintsTask.dispatch(HintsDispatchExecutor.java:229) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.14.jar:3.0.14]
at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDispatchExecutor$DispatchHintsTask.run(HintsDispatchExecutor.java:208) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.14.jar:3.0.14]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:79) [apache-cassandra-3.0.14.jar:3.0.14]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Digest mismatch exception
at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsReader$HintsIterator.computeNextInternal(HintsReader.java:216) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.14.jar:3.0.14]
at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsReader$HintsIterator.computeNext(HintsReader.java:190) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.14.jar:3.0.14]
... 16 common frames omitted
```

After some digging I found this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13696 and I think I need to delete hintfiles so nodes can come to a consistent state, but cassandra  is running in DCOS/mesosphere and I am not able to connect nodetool to truncate hintfiles

Any way I can delete hintfiles? Or any other way to make cluster consistent? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your files are probably getting corrupted.

I would try to keep your data in mount points managed by something like [Rex-Ray](http://rexray.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Thanks. For now we have recreated the cluster and repopulated the data but we could not find the solution of the problem which I think was due to corrupted hintfiles. We were able to connect to cqlsh on nodes momentarily and then they were failing.